# Javascript doesn't work on ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a problem with working JS in the Ajax call.
The JS works normaly until I get the new data from database or when I get ajax call.
Ajax call works normaly, just Javascript does not load.
Please help.

Here is the example index.php.

```
  <!-- library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/deleting_data.js"></script>
    <link href="css/forme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funkcije.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dinamicno_iskanje.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ausu-autosuggest.min.js"></script>

 <div id="load" align="center"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="28" height="28" align="absmiddle"/> Loading...</div>
  <div id="seek">//here comes refreshed data, with ajax call
 <table class="content" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px 5px; ">
     <?php  
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            //data from database
      </table></div>
  <div id="delete"></div> //ajax call for deleting data
```

And here is the refreshed_data.php

```
  <!-- library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/deleting_data.js"></script>
    <link href="css/forme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funkcije.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dinamicno_iskanje.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ausu-autosuggest.min.js"></script>

<div id="load" align="center"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="28" height="28" align="absmiddle"/> Loading...</div>
<table class="content" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px 5px; ">
 <?php  
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)
    {
        //refreshed data
    ?>
      </table>
       <div id="delete"></div>//ajax call for deleting data
```

And here is the deleting_data.js, whick works normaly when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$(".gumb").live("click",function(){
    $('#load').hide();
    $('#brisanje').hide();
});

$(function () {
    //$(".gumb").click(function() {
    $(".gumb").live("click", function () {

        $('#load').fadeIn();
        $('#brisanje').fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('#load').fadeOut();
        $('#brisanje').fadeOut(1000);

    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the ajax call?

Comment: I didn't post the ajax call, because it return the wanted result,just JS doesn't work after ajax call.

Comment: So, are you fetching javascript with the AJAX call which wont fire, or are you fetching something but the preexisting javascript will not fire?

Comment: looks like there is also issue with loading your js files why do you have jquery loaded twice? and is js/deleting_data.js using any jquery functions? if so why is it loaded before jQuery? and y are you including your libraries in every php file like refreshed_data.php and index.php?

Comment: I just wan't to work JS inside the ajax call. Libraries were included in every php file, beacause I was testing posibilities to work. Is it enough that I have included JS libraries only in the index.php?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for javascript to fire based on an elemenet created from an AJAX call, you need to remember your order of operations.  For example:  If you fired a .click event assignemnt at time 0, and then ajax some content at time 4 which produces a type that matches the parameters of the click event, it will not have the .click property assigned.  It is because the script to assign the click event was not applied to that element.  It would need to be reapplied by calling that .click function again.

Comment: I change the JS file, I use the live() function, and it worked,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

live() is depracated since jQuery 1.7
Try to use on() instead, like this :

```
$('rootselector').on('click', 'selector', function(){
   ...
});
```

With your code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.gumb', function() {
// your stuff
})
```

And for the record, you're including jQuery twice :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```